# CSS: I have a white bar at the top of my page

Tags: css, space

I have a white bar at the top of my page, and I don't know what in my code is causing it. I won't paste the whole thing here, because it is lengthy, but can someone view the source and maybe tell me what in the code is causing it to show up?

http://ddofans.org/design3/

Comment: `I won't paste the whole thing here, because it is lengthy` Please do **not** post links to pages as the question is of no use to future users with similar issues when the link is dead or the page is changed (i.e:  issue fixed!) not allowing to reproduce the issue. Post the relevant HTML, Script and CSS in your question directly and if possible add a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsFiddle.net) (or similar) to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I appologize, I didn't know. I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because you have `hr.fancy-line:before` and after positioned absolute which takes it out of the flow of your document. You can make you `.container {position:relative;}` which is a possible fix.

This is located in design3.css line 104

```
hr.fancy-line:before, hr.fancy-line:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
```

It could also be on line 124 of design3.css

```
body, hr.fancy-line:after {
background: #F4F4F4;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, I realized it was the positioning that was messing it up. I removed the absolute position from it, and it went away. Thankyou so much, again :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the following line:

> `hr.fancy-line:after { background: #f4f4f4; }`

design3.css line 124

you can delete this line if you donot need it